# How to add .htaccess exception to specific files in subdirectories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess generated in my /thumbnails folder and I want missing images to fall back on default.jpg.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ default.jpg [NC,L]
```

Next, I want to exclude any scrumb.jpg files inside subfolders.

This is an example URL, the fallback should work:

```
http://url.com/thumbnails/96Hjta6C/oijfwjoiaffwe99.jpg
```

The fallback should not work in this case, and should proceed as regularly, with a 404 error:

```
http://url.com/thumbnails/96Hjta6C/scrumb.jpg
```

What rewrite condition do I have to add to the .htaccess file that is located in the /thumbnails folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to build on the Rewrites you already have, you could just add a RewriteCond at the top to check for /scrumb.jpg. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/scrumb\.jpg$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ default.jpg [NC,L]
```